# How do i install Google Play Store on a chinese phone?

Tags: google-play-store

I just got this Weimi P8 with a wonderful configuration and features. unfortunately, it doesn't come with a Google Play Store.  I installed 1 manually by sending the apk file from another phone but it doesn't come up whenever I start it up. any idea how I can get around this glitch without rooting?

Whenever  I attempt the computer way, it shows installed because I already have a Google account.
Thanks.

Comment: You're not allowed to install the Play Store on a phone that doesn't come with it. That's software piracy. Phone manufacturers have to do a lot of compatibility tests and pay money to Open Handset Alliance before their phone is allowed to run Google Play.

Comment: Tobi, please see our [google-apps tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info) which explains how to obtain and flash the Google Apps to a device not shipping with them.